# Awkward hyperlink generation in HTML Mails

Tags: ios, email, gmail

I'm struggling with my E-Mail Marketing System, i am able now to send more or less beautiful HTML E-Mails over the net but now i'm facing some awkward problems in the rendering - Customers keep asking me why there are so ugly links in their Newsletters and where they appears, they didn't have any links in the Newsletter Text.

So... the bad guys here are some superb technology brothers like iOS or GMail, doing their own stuff in rendering HTML-Mails like "oooh, that's probably a phone number, i mark thats as a link!" And.. yea.. in standard-mails this is nice but now i'm wondering how i can kill that functionality...

Are there any meta-tags or other possibilities to tell these guys to not do that in my newsletter-mails?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what browser do you use?

It is a extention in your browser, find it and delete or disable

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn that feature off in iOS. Only if you create your own app for iOS or you create own webpage, it is possible to turn that off. Maybe you should switch to another e-mail client. :)

Comment: Thank you, i was afraid that this problem is sort of "unsolvable" ^^

Answer (score 0):

Wrap an empty href tag around it:

```
<a href="" style="color: #000001; text-decoration: none;">Not a hyperlink</a>
```

(Gmail ignores #000000 and #FFFFFF colors in links, which is why I have #000001)

Alternatively you can try and disguise phone numbers and addresses with `&nbsp;` between the words/numbers. Something like this:

```
address: 123&nbsp;My&nbsp;Address<br>
phone: 123&nbsp;456&nbsp;789
```