# Removing Underlined Links On Email On iPhone

Tags: html, css, email

I don't know if this is just happening for iPhone or all smartphones as I only have access to an iPhone at this moment but it is forcing underlining on all links.

I have added `text-decoration:none;` to the `span` **AND** the `a` element both using in-line styles and classes but it still shows, below is the code:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" style="text-decoration: none;" class="appleLinks">

<span style="text-decoration:none;" class="appleLinks" >

Example Link

</span>

</a>
```

I also have the following in my `<head>` section inside `<style>` tags:

```
a               { text-decoration: none; }
a:link          { text-decoration: none; }
a:visited       { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover         { text-decoration: none; }
a:active        { text-decoration: none; }
a:focus         { text-decoration: none; }

.appleLinks     { text-decoration: none; }
```

I can't think what else I could add to the links to make the underlining disappear

Comment: can you clear the cache from settings and check again??

Comment: Might be worth looking at this : https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/ipad/ios-blue-links

Comment: Hey @NickR... I read that and it didn't work for me... Nathan I'll try the cache reset.

Comment: try a:link {text-decoration:none;}

Comment: @NathanLee I tried the cache thing but it didn't solve it and koningdavid I have put that in my style tags at the top and that hasn't worked either

Comment: give online link of page

Comment: http://dev.networkintellect4.info/work/myevo/newsletter/salon.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about losing the inner span and just doing:

```
<a href="" style="color: #000001; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Link</a>
```

This always works fine (At least on Litmus previews anyway).

UPDATE:

Try this:

```
.appleLinks a  { text-decoration: none !important; }
```

Reference [here](https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices). I'm thinking the a is because there is a href put in there dynamically by your client.

Comment: On a side note, if you want to remove the unwanted hyperlinking of phone numbers, addresses etc, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188499/awkward-hyperlink-generation-in-html-mails/17191937#17191937

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone I know it was a while ago, but just updated the answer to something that should work.

Comment: thanks for the update more than 6 months later, much appreciated! I will certainly try this next time i need it and let you know how I get on!

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone Yeah, I was just answering a similar question and stumbled back across this...

Answer (score 1):

The best thing that works for me is:

```
a[href^=tel] { color:#000000 !important; text-decoration:none !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
a               { text-decoration: none !important; }
a:link          { text-decoration: none !important; }
a:visited       { text-decoration: none !important; }
a:hover         { text-decoration: none !important; }
a:active        { text-decoration: none !important; }
a:focus         { text-decoration: none !important; }

.appleLinks     { text-decoration: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that some clients (Apple Mail, specifically) apply border styles to `a` tags. The following CSS worked for me:

```
a[class="no_underline"] {text-decoration:none !important; border-bottom:none;}
```